# How to delete the last photo in Swift iOS8?

Tags: ios, swift, camera-roll

I try to get the last photo from camera roll and delete it.Now I get the last photo but have problems in deleting the last photo.
I tried this way but I delete all photos,so I plan to build a new PHFetchResult which only include the last photo but I don't know how to do that.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges( {
      PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(fetchResult)},
      completionHandler: { 
      success, error in
      NSLog("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error))
      })
```

Thank all of you to answer my question!

Answer (score 7):

I guess the problem lies in your `fetchResult`.
You will have to pass an array that contains only latest image from photo library.

Try making that array as follows-

```
var fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    var fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)

    if (fetchResult.lastObject != nil) {

        var lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.lastObject as PHAsset

        let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: lastAsset)

        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges( {
            PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(arrayToDelete)},
            completionHandler: {
                success, error in
                NSLog("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error))
        }) 



    }
```

See this [link](http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/1/5/get-last-photo-from-camera-roll-in-swift-xcode-6-ios-8-tutorial).

[image]

Comment: Thanks,but my problem is how to make an Array by using lastAsset and pass that array to deleteAssets method.Could you please tell me more code and details.

Comment: Is there any way to hide don't allow button because in my scenario, I want user to delete the image.

Comment: what if wihout allow?