# How to detect when iOS is about to take a screenshot?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a page in my app where I want to to hide some content when users take a screenshot.
I tried to observe `UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification` but it only notifies the observer after the screenshot is taken.
I also tried to override `touchesCancelled` but it also didn't work.

Comment: Quick searching will tell you that you ***cannot*** prevent screenshots on iOS. Even if you could, what's to stop someone grabbing another phone and taking a photo?

Comment: but we can forcefully delete the screenshot after detecting it without knowing the user
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731764/observe-and-delete-screenshot-if-a-screenshot-is-taken-while-using-my-app-in

Comment: @Adarsh If you would implement something like this - deleting the latest photo - I would immediatly delete your app from my device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible and legal to disable home button and the screenshot feature in an ipad app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557701/is-it-possible-and-legal-to-disable-home-button-and-the-screenshot-feature-in-an)